How do I add a custom column on Category Blog view of articles on Joomla 5?
There are options to show author and hits and dates, but I want to add my own.
How do I do it?
And then, how do I label each article so that the custom column will show up in the category blog list.
Thanks in advance

Too much to explain via a forum
The principle is that you take a copy of one or more existing joomla files and change them. This can be done completely safely and is a standard Joomla process, albeit somewhat advanced. I use this often and usually I mark a number of existing lines of PHP code as comments and add new lines with the content and formatting that I want.
There is a lot of information to be found, below are some links
Good luck,
Didier.
https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides
https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Template_Overrides
https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/template-overrides-articles/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efQ_3nVVLhs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Vf2mnjgfjU

I think you can create template overrides for that. I created the following overrides for my template:
html/layouts/joomla/content/info_block/category.php
html/layouts/joomla/content/info_block.php"
Didier.

Thanks, but I'll need a step by step guide on how to do that. I'm too much of a novice to try and write the coding myself.
